# How can I write Shell script for default parameter setting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In shell script, How can I set 0 as default value to parameter.

```
param2=0
${2:-0}
```

and

```
${2:-param2}
```

These result is `0: not found`

and

```
param=$5 
S{1:-$param}
```

is active. but $0 mean shell script name. I want to use number 0.

Comment: For me it it is not clear what you want to do. If `$2` is unset or enpty, `${2:-0}` is expanded to `0`. As your script now contains a line `0`, the shell tries to execute a command or program named `0` and complains because it doesn't find such a program. You should add a few lines more code to show what you want to achieve. I also don't understand what you mean with "but $0 mean shell script name. I want to use number 0."

Comment: Do you want `param=$2`, but `param=0` if there is no second positional argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "param: $param"        # param is not defined
echo "param: ${param-0}"    # use 0 as default
param=99                    # set a value for param
echo "param: ${param-0}"    # ignore the default
```

output:

```
param: 
param: 0
param: 99
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand problems like this, add `set -x` before the code. That will tell you that `${2:-0}` is expanded to `0`. The shell thinks this is a command and tries to execute it.

This will be easier to understand if you look at this code:

```
cmd=echo
${cmd} test
```

If you run this, `${cmd}` is replaced with `echo`.

In your code, you probably want to assign the result of `${2:-0}` to a new variable:

```
foo=${2:-0}
```

Comment: You can't assign directly to `$2` (and you would use `:=`, not `:-`, for such assignments).

Comment: The OP might want `param=${2:-0}`.

Comment: @chepner when use ```:=``` , I get error ```Bad substitution``` .  but `param=${2:0} is very useful. Thank you

Comment: *How* did you use `:=`? It's just as standard as `:-`.

Comment: @chepner Oops. Fixed.